# Enlarged GNOME notifications

Tags: gnome-shell, notification

My on-screen notifications on GNOME on Ubuntu 18.04 are enlarged, and look that way on the notification tray too.
[image: Enlarged notification panel]

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new .notify-osd file with manual configuration was enough to sort this issue out. 
https://www.maketecheasier.com/customize-the-notification-bubble-in-ubuntu-raring/

Comment: Please consider expanding your answer a bit more (e.g. *how* exactly you configured it) to help future users. Link-only answers are not accepted here.